# C console output hidden while awaiting input

Tags: c, eclipse, input, console, output

Hi I'm trying some C coding on Eclipse, and I had a problem:

I am trying to print some text, however, while awaiting input from the user, the text actually fails to appear until AFTER the user has input.

Here is an example of what I mean:
TEST

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){

    char c[5];  
    printf("test\n");  //PRINTING 'test' BEFORE i have to enter code    
    fgets(c, 5, stdin);     
    printf("You entered: %s\n", c);

    return 0; 
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
dog (this is what i typed)
test
You entered: dog
```

Rather than appearing BEFORE I am prompted to enter code, the "test" printf only appears AFTER I have entered the code.

Comment: `char c[5]` should be `char c[5+1]`.

Comment: Maybe your environment takes some time in loading the program, so that you manage to write your input before the program starts properly with the output (how unlikely it seems to be)? If you wait a while, does the output *still* not happen? Did you remember to build your program (as you show it to us) before running it? Is the newline in the string you print there in your actual program? And lastly, if you run your program manually instead from within Eclipse, do you still have the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this text to print is still waiting in the buffer (that's an optimization, to group data to write to make it more efficient). To make sure everything from buffer gets out to the console you should flush it like this

```
fflush(stdout);
```

or you can use a function that does not use buffering like (on linux)

```
write()
```